# How do I ask someone politely not to use "Don" when referring to me, but just to use my first name?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I have a tutor-student relationship with the person.  We refer to each other as "usted" but I don't want to be called "Don (my first name)"; it feels too hierarchical.

Comment: «Por favor, no me trate por «don» / no use «don» conmigo, prefiero “…”». For me, it'd be odd, though, to use first name with usted.  Be ready for Sr/Lic/Ing/Dr(ª) [surname], instead.

Comment: I'd say "No me trate de 'don'. Llámeme (directamente) por el nombre de pila".

Comment: Are you teaching someone Spanish or English? If you are teaching them English, I understand the question. If you are teaching them Spanish, I do not.

Comment: I'm teaching Spanish speakers English.

Answer (score 4):

Just let the other person know about the fact that it makes you uncomfortable, that you feel it like an overly formal treatment.

> **Por favor, no me diga Don.** (Sé que busca ser respetuoso pero me pone incómodo la distancia de tanta formalidad) 
>
> **¡Con que me diga `<your name>` está bien! / [es suficiente]**.

Comment: a mí me suena mejor _no me digas DE Don_. Igual que decimos _no me hable DE usted_

Comment: Si. Seguramente esa manera sea regionalmente variable. En Argentina diríamos `no me trate "de Don"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be careful here what you ask for. If you want to be addressed by your first name you are inviting a move away from usted which the student may be very uncomfortable with depending on the ambient level of formality in your institution.

I used to try to get visiting students to address me by my first name as I felt that travelling to a foreign country was partly about adopting the customs of that country. When some of them continued to call me professor I eventually decided that it was not my job to make them uncomfortable so I stopped insisting.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but the professor is only demanding not to be called 'Don'. He remains addressing his student as 'usted', signaling his intention of sticking to that respectful tone.